# Pixel Manipulation via GUI in Python (poss PIL, Tkinter)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pixel

Here's the issue -

I'm writing a program that will iterate through a series of image manipulations - both effecting the whole image as well as just portions of the image.  I need to demonstrate these changes to the user (myself) so I can see what's going wrong with my manipulations as they take place.

I originally tried to use PIL and Tkinter to do this - but I couldn't even load an image into the GUI - here's a bit of code formed from the corners of the web, via many google searches:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
import time

class Test(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.c = Canvas(self, width=574, height=431, bg="red")
        self.c.pack()
        Button(self, text="Process", command=self.procImg).pack()
        Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit).pack()
    def procImg(self):
        t = time.time()
        self.flashImg = Image.open("./in_img/resize.bmp")
        #self.flashImg = flashImg.resize((574, 431))
        self.flashImg = self.flashImg.convert("L")
        #self.photo = ImageTk.BitmapImage(flashImg)
        self.c.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.flashImg)
        self.c.create_image(574, 431, anchor=NW, image=self.c.photo)
        self.c.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill="blue")
        self.update()
        print time.time()-t

t = Test()
t.pack()
t.mainloop()
```

So the above code is pretty bad, I know - but I wanted to post something to prove that I have at least been working at this.

Can anyone suggest to me a new way of approaching this problem using Python?  I'd rather not learn a different language - I'm new to the Tkinter library so if something else is better suited for this, I have no issues learning a new library.

Also, FYI, the "resize.bmp" image is a resized .JPG from a digital camera.  I tried that one too and it didn't work - I really need to find a way to flash bitmaps from memory to the screen in a GUI so I can adjust parameters as the processing is going on.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is probably there. It's just not visible.

Instead of :

```
self.c.create_image(574, 431, anchor=NW, image=self.c.photo)
```

try :

```
self.c.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=self.c.photo)
```

---

Also, if you keep a reference to the canvas image item, you can swap different images in and out.

eg. (self.canvasItem) below :

```
from Tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw, ImageOps, ImageEnhance


class ImageButcher(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        #create ui
        f = Frame(self, bd=2)

        self.colour = StringVar(self)
        self.colourMenu = OptionMenu(f, self.colour,
                                     *('red','green','blue','white'))
        self.colourMenu.config(width=5)
        self.colour.set('red')
        self.colourMenu.pack(side='left')

        self.rectangleButton = Button(f, text='Rectangle',
                                    command=self.draw_rectangle)
        self.rectangleButton.pack(side='left')

        self.brightenButton = Button(f, text='Brighten',
                                    command=self.on_brighten)
        self.brightenButton.pack(side='left')

        self.mirrorButton = Button(f, text='Mirror',
                                    command=self.on_mirror)
        self.mirrorButton.pack(side='left')
        f.pack(fill='x')

        self.c = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        width=100, height=100)
        self.c.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        #load image
        im = Image.open('IMG_1584.JPG')
        im.thumbnail((512,512))

        self.tkphoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        self.canvasItem = self.c.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=self.tkphoto)
        self.c.config(width=im.size[0], height=im.size[1])

        self.img = im
        self.temp = im.copy() # 'working' image

    def display_image(self, aImage):
        self.tkphoto = pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(aImage)
        self.c.itemconfigure(self.canvasItem, image=pic)

    def on_mirror(self):
        im = ImageOps.mirror(self.temp)
        self.display_image(im)
        self.temp = im

    def on_brighten(self):
        brightener = ImageEnhance.Brightness(self.temp)
        self.temp = brightener.enhance(1.1) # +10%
        self.display_image(self.temp)

    def draw_rectangle(self):
        bbox = 9, 9, self.temp.size[0] - 11, self.temp.size[1] - 11        
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.temp)
        draw.rectangle(bbox, outline=self.colour.get())
        self.display_image(self.temp)


app = ImageButcher()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dude that works.  Epic- this answers my question.  Thank you!